# Downvoting critique questions answers?

Tags: discussion, critique

I just ran into an old [critique question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8024/18168) where one of the answers offered a remix of the OP's work suggesting new leads.

My question is: since critique questions are already considered opinion-based for the most part, is it good practice to downvote an answer that makes the original work worse (IMO)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Without seeing the original Q it's kind of hard to judge this individual case, but here's my general view:*

I think it's good practice to downvote what you think is a bad answer. Regardless of the nature of the question.

If you really think the answer makes the original work *worse*, by all means downvote **and** leave a comment saying just that. Maybe substantiate a bit why you think the work is worse.

If you really want to step it up a notch you can invite the user(s) to [The Looking Glass](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass) or a private chat to discuss their works and what you think makes them better or worse.

---

<sup>*EDIT after OP linked to original Q:*</sup>

<sup>Since the question is five years old I don't think there is much impact still to be had. The user was last active four years ago, so I don't think they would mind losing 2 rep to a downvote. The OP has probably moved on, the logo is either in use or it isn't. Nevertheless, the above still stands: **downvote, comment, leave it**.</sup>